# make text vertically centered in parent, relative only to size of lowercase letters

Tags: html, css

I want to vertically center my text in its parent div. My problem is I'm using only lowercase letters. This leads to the text theoretically being vertically centered, but looking off.

Is there a way to make the text position relative to the size of its lowercase letters only (without doing something like specifying the height in pixels or something similar)?

Here's an image of what I'm talking about:

[image: off looking centered text]

Comment: Well also lowercase letters, such as "f" and "h" can/do have a full font height.
I think there will never be something like you're looking for in CSS.
The only way is to use "line-height" or different paddings for the top and bottom of the container. Maybe you can find a font that has fitting properties for your situation.

Comment: How do you center your text vertically actually ?